# How to render good quality image from 3d scene in java/c++

Tags: java, c++, 3d, rendering

i need to develop simple 3d application ( i don't know if its going to be java or c++ ) 
now how to use 3d engine i know , but in the end i need to produce rendered image or movie 
out of the 3d scene. 
who should i do it in application ?

Comment: Your question is much too vague to answer. Please tell us what you have done, and where you are having problems. Otherwise the question will probably be closed.

Comment: well the best description is for example in application like 3dsmax
when you hit the render button there is process that render the 3d mash with the mapping into image that is good quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an image with really good quality I think you should use a 3D engine with ray tracing.

Implementing a raytracer might not be a easy task, so my recommendation is to use an existing one, like for example [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/). I think it's possible to embed it in other applications. Raytracing stills takes some time, so the rendering will not be in real time.

In Java you can use Java3D but you will need some work.

Answer (score 1):

Java 3D API 
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/

Answer (score 0):

At
http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/#4

you'll find a description on how to render images to an Image instance, and how to save that to a file in Java